# Can multiple quarter digits be rejected when parsing a YearQuarter using ThreeTen-Extra?

Tags: java, java-time

I am using [YearQuarter](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) from the [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to represent a particular quarter within a given year.

I am using a custom format rather than the default format, e.g. "3Q2018" instead of "2018-Q3" for the third quarter of 2018.  When parsing a value through [YearQuarter.parse(text, formatter)](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-), I want values with leading zeros for the quarter to be rejected (via the standard [DateTimeParseException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html)).

My first attempt was to use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Q'Q'yy")`.  However, this accepts strings with arbitrarily many leading zeros in front of the quarter.  For instance, neither "02Q2007" nor "002Q2007" are rejected by this formatter.

This does seem consistent with how the single character patterns are handled for other temporal types.  For instance, these successfully parse without error:

```
YearMonth.parse("012-2018", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-yyyy"))
LocalTime.parse("001:00:01", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss"))
LocalTime.parse("01:00:012", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:s"))
```

However, these reject the input with a `DateTimeParseException`:

```
YearMonth.parse("012-2018", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-yyyy"))
LocalTime.parse("001:00:01", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))
LocalTime.parse("01:00:012", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))
```

How can I construct a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) to parse a `YearQuarter` in my desired format while rejecting values with more than one digit for the quarter?  Ideally, I'd like to do this as a pattern string, as those are easier for humans to read and are much easier externalize as textual properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not discovered a way to do this as a pattern string, but the following will programmatically construct a `DateTimeFormatter` with the desired format, rejecting 0-padded quarters:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields;

[...]

new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR, 1)
    .appendLiteral('Q')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
    .toFormatter();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a pattern string then I fear there is no way within the context of `DateTimeFormatter`, but I have successfully tested my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) if it provides the desired behaviour:

```
    ChronoFormatter<CalendarQuarter> f =
        ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
            "Q'Q'uuuu", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT, CalendarQuarter.chronology());
    CalendarQuarter cq = f.parse("3Q2018");
    System.out.println(cq); // 2018-Q3
    f.parse("13Q2018"); // exception
    f.parse("03Q2018"); // exception
```

An object of type [CalendarQuarter](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/CalendarQuarter.html) corresponds to `YearQuarter` so you will find similar methods to change it to a gregorian date, for example:

```
    CalendarQuarter cq = f.parse("3Q2018");
    LocalDate ld = cq.atEndOfQuarter().toTemporalAccessor();
    System.out.println(ld); // 2018-09-30
```